# Upload File and Save in Database in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

It's a Modal in my form and I want to upload file here and Add data attachment and after filling form I save all the data in Database but I don't know how to upload and save modal first.
Client side:

```
             <Modal @ref="modalRef">
                <ModalBackdrop />
                <ModalContent Centered="true">
                      <ModalBody>
                        <Field>
                            <FieldLabel>فایل</FieldLabel>
                            <FileEdit Filter=".jpg, .png, .gif"  Changed="@OnChanged" 
                            Written="@OnWritten" Progressed="@OnProgressed" />
                        </Field>
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="@HideModal">Cancle</Button>
                        <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@AddAtachment">AddAttachment</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </ModalContent>
            </Modal>

      string TitleAttachment;
```

server side:
These 2 classes, one of them is for Attachment (Modal) and one of them is for Main form and the have different view model and cofig.

```
   public class ClaimAttachmentInfo
   {
    private ClaimAttachmentInfo()
    {
    }

    public ClaimAttachmentInfo(string title, byte[] attachmentContent, string fileExtension)
    {
    
        Title = title;
        AttachmentContent = attachmentContent;
        FileExtension = fileExtension;
    }
    public long ClaimAttachmentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] AttachmentContent { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
}

  public class ClaimInfo
{

    public long ClaimId { get; set; }
    public string ClaimCode { get; set; }
    public string ChassisNo { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string NationalityCode { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public long Creator { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int VehicleTypeId { get; set; }
            
    **public IEnumerable<ClaimAttachmentInfo> ClaimAttachmentsInfos { get; set; }**
   }
```

Comment: So your question is how to upload files and save to the database or do not know how to display Modal?

Comment: I want to know how upload files and save to database

Comment: See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0).